# No "+STIN:" response after entering password with the help of "AT+STGR=3,1"

Tags: at-command

I am trying to run SIM toolkit application with the help of AT commands. No any problem to

```
"Get information about the main menu" (AT+STGI=0),
"Select Item from the main menu" (AT+STGR=0,1,1),
"Select Item from the submenu" (AT+STGR=6,1,1),
"Input User information" (AT+STGR=3,1<CR>>0123<Ctrl Z>).
```

But it is impossible to receive SIM response when I am entering password. I expect to receive "+STIN:" response after OK to continue my session. When I am trying to get STIN status with the help of AT+STIN? request it replies "+CME ERROR: 4 Operation not supported.".

I meet this trouble with the new SIM cards, which contain a little modified SIM application. As the older SIM cards with older version of the application there is no any problem to input password with the help of standard way (AT+STGR=3,1).

I may suppose that the software developer add an encryption or any other technique for inputting password. Unfortunately currently there is no any chance to contact with the software developer. On the other hand there is an insufficient information/documentation on this theme.

Can anyone advise me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The SIM application waited a terminal response. I could not find a way to send required response with the help of "AT+STGR" or other SIM toolkit commands, but I had succeeded with AT+CSIM.

```
AT+CSIM=40,"a01400000f810301270002028281030100240101"
```

I hope it could be useful to anyone, who would like to run and manage SIM application with the help of AT commands

Comment: what is the 40 used for?

Comment: 40 is length, I am also looking for the command breakdown. See here too:  (https://forum.sierrawireless.com/viewtopic.php?f=159&t=6714)